# IIS8 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: c#

How can I disable the server asking for credentials for a set directory and all subdirectories? I have got Windows Authentication installed.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to clarify further on why you want to do this, all access permissions should be controlled via the application.

However, right click the folder in question and add Everyone, with read permissions.

Edit:

Based off your new comment. Disable Windows Authentication and enable Anonymous access to the site. This is for IIS7 but the principle is the same: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731244(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I want to disable authentication and allow free access for everyone.

Comment: Revised my answer above

Comment: I have disabled windows authentication and enabled anonymous yet I get `Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.` if I try to access any of the subdirectories.

Comment: Does the application pool have the correct credentials to view the folders

Answer (score 0):

Open the `Inetmgr` and go to `authentication section`. And enable/disable the required authentication modes.

Comment: I have disabled windows authentication and enabled anonymous yet I get Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. if I try to access any of the subdirectories.

Comment: Enable directory browsing.

Comment: @user2605450 - Is this resolved your problem, or you are still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything in these posts. 
Step 1: Click on the Edit Permission Link under the Action

Step 2: Select the Share Tab

Step 3: Under the Network File and Folder Share section we have "Share" Button ,Click on the Button

Step 4: In the Dropdown you have choose "Everyone" and Click on the "Add" Button.

This is working for me.